# Travis CI - Test fail on Travis (401 and 400) but works locally Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, travis-ci

I'm trying to unit test some requests from my Java Spring Boot application and they seem to work locally, but they all fail when I test them on Travis CI. Even a simple get request fails and I can't seem to find the problem. I use MockMvc to mock the server.

I noticed all the test fails with error code 400 or 401. And expected is 200. Here an example of very simple test:

```java
@Test
    public void getInstruments() throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = get("/instrument");

        MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(request).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();

        String body = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();

        Instrument[] instruments = gson.fromJson(body,Instrument[].class);

        assertNotNull(instruments);
        assertEquals("Piano",instruments[0].getDescription());
        assertEquals("Gitaar",instruments[1].getDescription());
        assertEquals("Viool",instruments[2].getDescription());
        assertEquals("Drum",instruments[3].getDescription());
    }
```

A get request made with MockHttpServletRequestBuilder and expecting and returning the result. I debugged the code. Instruments is not empty and when I run the test locally it works all fine.

I also use JWT but everyone can call this request, even if not authenticated.

I hope someone can help me out.

travis.yml file:

```
language: java
jdk:
  - openjdk11
script:
  - mvn clean install
services:
  - postgresql
```

[image: Error]

Comment: 400 or 401 is quite a difference. The first is a bad request, the second security related. So quite different options. The interesting part is probably before the exception happens, another thing is that there is an error regarding a non-existing table, which could be the cause of all the issues you have. Also make sure the environments are the same (OS, JDK, versions etc. etc.) as something locally with JDK 8 might not work on JDK11 (or vice-versa).

Comment: @M.Deinum Yeah I saw that it says "user" does not exist. What do you mean with the environments, and JDK 8 and JDK11? I use JDK 11 and also put that in my travis.yml file. I edited my question and added the yml file.

Comment: That the config of the environments is comparable. The difference in JDK was a sample of that. Make sure you are using the same JDK (vendor and patch level wise) else you also might run into weird results (IBM acts different then OpenJDK for instance in certain cases). Apparently the DB cannot be created leading to test errors. Please don't post stacktraces, logging etc. as images as those are unreadable, post the text in proper code blocks.

Comment: @M.Deinum hmm Ok that's clear. But where can I compare the config of the environments ? Where can I find that ?

Comment: I assume you know which OS, java version etc. you are using locally...

Comment: @M.Deinum haha yes, I use Windows and Java JDK 11. But to what should I compare that to ?? :P

Comment: What you are using on TravisCI (although that is dockerized). But looking at the logs i suspect the main issue is no DB connection or tables being created. Which is probably something different in Travis and locally (either locally in-memory DB or locally installed Postgres).

Comment: @M.Deinum I Just connected my github account with Travis CI. The only thing I did was add postgresql in the yml file. I did not configure anything on their website. I use postgresql locally for my db. Hmm could that mean I should use Hibernate to auto create the db?

Comment: Well don't use hibernate but rather something like flyway to manage your schema. Also when using multiple containers it probably isn't accessible through localhost (although I would expect a total failure starting your application in the first place).

Comment: @M.Deinum hmm never heard of flyway before. I also was thinking just to create the db via the yml file. https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#postgresql

Comment: Only creating the db isn't enouhg, you need tables as well. Also how are you going to update the db for the next release? Drop everything and re-create, probably not going to work in a real-world scenario.

Comment: @M.Deinum True, I also need tables. hmm and what if I use spring hibernate to update the table everytime I commit and push?

Comment: You really don't want to use Hibernate to migrate the tables. What if you drop a column or move columns to a different table. You need to migrate/fix data, Hibernate isn't going to do all this for you (it is kind of blunt force and should only be used in testing scenarios or the initial schema generation, which you can put into a proper tool like flyway or liquibase).

Comment: @M.Deinum ok I will try to use flyway, but one thing, I put psql -c 'create database postgres;' -U postgres in my yml. Then I get this error in the logs : ERROR:  database "postgres" already exists. Does this mean Travis sees my db already?

Comment: I don't have the logs, but if the db doesn't exists the application would fail to start for the integration test, which would result in a different exception (actually no tests would be run).

Comment: @M.Deinum So the db does already exist. And the test do run, but with a 401 error code.  I see that it builds correctly, and the application does start. I don't get it anymore, what can it be that it gives me a 401 everytime...

Comment: no access/no user, wrong right of user. Apparently you have a pre-filled db locally which doesn;t exist on the server

Comment: @M.Deinum Ok I'm going to test it with a database on Heroku

Comment: @M.Deinum nvm that is not going to work, I get illegalexceptions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215097/discussion-between-appel-taart-and-m-deinum).